# command page with the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frame

I wonder if there is some way for me to perform actions on the page using the iframe inside it, eg by clicking a link in the frame it hidden divs from the page the frame is. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

If your main-document and the iframe-document are on the same domain, this is possible to access elements in within the frame:

```
document.frames['frame-name'].contentDocument.getElementById('elemId').style.display = 'none';
```

Or to access your parent-document

```
window.parent.contentDocument.getElementById('elemId').style.display = 'none';
```

Comment: Great! however I would like this function was performed in frame to the page not the page for the frame.